# Unity 2d game - why is my static stat resetting to 100 when scene changes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I have 2 scenes with a "healthbar" they both have the following script on them. They should both show the current HP / maxHP eg 50/100. However when the scene changes it goes back to 100/100. The static variable current health somehow changes to 100 when the scene changes.

health stat script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class Stat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int maxHealth;
    public static int currentHealth;

    public GameObject thisObject;
    public Slider slider;
    public TMP_Text statText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        maxHealth = 100;
        SetMaxValue(maxHealth);
        currentHealth = 100;
        SetValue(currentHealth);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += OnActiveSceneChanged;
    }
    void OnActiveSceneChanged(Scene oldScene, Scene newScene)
    {
        Debug.Log(currentHealth);
    }
    public void SetMaxValue(int value)
    {
        slider.maxValue = value;
        slider.value = value;
    }

    public void SetValue(int value)
    {
        slider.value = value;
        if (thisObject != null)
        {
            if (gameObject.name == "Health")
            {
                statText.text = currentHealth + " / " + maxHealth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[the health stat is only changed through 2 scripts - the stat and the boat scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMQaW.png)

boat script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Boat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stat health;
    public GameOverScreen GameOverScreen;

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        Stat.currentHealth -= amount;
        health.SetValue(Stat.currentHealth);

        if(Stat.currentHealth <= 0)
            GameOverScreen.GameOver();
    }
}
```

I would assume the problem is because of the Awake function since it sets the health to 100 but it should only call once in a lifetime. I can't think of any other reason that the stat magically changes to 100 when the scene changes.

Also the only purpose of  using onactivescenechanged here is because I was trying to fix the bug, the bug occurs without that too.

Comment: I never used static variables for health, it works well without the variables being static. Also DO NOT SET the `maxHealth` and `currentHealth` in the `Awake()` method. Setup them in the Unity Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static means "The variable is shared among all class instances". it doesn't mean it holds the value when your class is destroyed. when you load a new scene, the previous scene is destroyed, therefore the values are destroyed, too. You need to save your state somewhere and the easiest way is using PlayerPrefs

so before loading your new scene, save your value like this

```
PlayerPrfs.SetInt("currentHealthValue", currentHealth);
```

and then retrieve the value like  this

```
int currentHealth = PlayerPrfs.GetInt("currentHealthValue", 0);
```

that 0 is optional, means if there is no value, return 0 or any other value you write there.

I recommend you to use JSON which is bit advance and best solution : https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

PlayerPrefs : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html